# Is there a way to line up the boxes

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using react semantic ui and I am trying to line up the boxes in the columns together. The paragraph pushes up the boxes that they end up not being aligned. Would it better to create another row of columns?
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/aligningboxes-610xh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Custom Class on `<Grid>` tag

```
<Grid className="content-div">
```

And add this css to your `style.css`

```
.content-div {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

it will line up on the same level as your expectation.

Comment: hmm the boxes are still not lined up

Comment: @xzeta glad to know that it's working. Expecting upvote and selected answer. Thanks.